# C++ "While" Loop

Tags: c++, while-loop

I'm struggling to apply a "While" loop to the following problem: Design the logic for a program that allows a user to enter a number. Display the sum of every number from one through the entered number.

```
Start
    int userNumber;
    Declarations
        int number = 1
    while number <= userNumber
        ++number
    endwhile
    output number
Stop
```

I know my code isn't correct as it is just adding one to the initial value until the user's number is reached, thus making the output the user's number. How would I go about adding each subsequent value without writing them out e.g. user's number is 10, so the program would add 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 and output the total of 55?

Thank you!

Comment: Just accumulate them into a sum. What's so hard about that?

Comment: Your code does not appear to be C++, are you sure you tagged the question correctly? Also you are not receiving the number from the user nor are you accumulating, only calculating the numbers between 1 and the given number.

Comment: @Guvante, I removed the C++ tag. I am programming in C++, but this was just some rough pseudocode to help explain where my thinking currently was (hence the mistakes).

Comment: @Lee Daniel Crocker, no need to be rude and assume that I should automatically know how to accumulate.

Comment: @Anonymous - if you are loking for a c++ solution don't remove the c++ tag. :) But you should have stated: This pseudo code, how can I do that in c++.

Comment: @Nielsen, that was my mistake. Re-added the C++ tag.

Comment: @Anonymous: You should modify your pseudo code to be actual c++. Stackoverflow uses the actual language as the basis for communication as everyone here who can help knows c++ better than your own variant of pseudo code. Also having a minimal program helps better define where to go next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tip. You'll want to start at the users number and count down to 0. Like this:

```
int finalNum = 0;
int userNum;
//This is where you need to get the user's number....
while(userNum > 0)
{
    finalNum += userNum;
    userNum--;
}
//Do whatever you need to finalNum....
```

EDIT: It appears you've posted pseudocode; usually a big no-no here unless stated otherwise. It's better to post the actual code as it's easier to tell what exactly is going on.

Comment: thank you for your help. I think this is the way I was trying to do it. Sorry about the pseudocode. I don't remember reading anything that warned against it.

Answer (score 0):

The function you need could look like this for c++:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calc(unsigned x)
{
    unsigned t = 0;             // Assume the result to be 0 (zero)
    for (i = 1; i <= x; i++)    // Continue until i is greater than x
    {
         t += i;                // Accumulate, i.e. t = t +i
    }
    cout << "sum=" << t << endl; // Print the result
}

int main()
{
    calc(10);
    return 0;
}
```

An alternative is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void calc(unsigned x)
{
    cout << "sum=" << (x*(x+1)/2) << endl; // Print the result
}

int main()
{
    calc(10);
    return 0;
}
```

This works because the sum of all integers from 1 to n is n*(n+1)/2